# Send base 64 string with alomofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I trying to send post request with dictionary, one of its value is base64 string. So, I have parameters dict as follows:

```
let paramsDict : [String : Any] = [ "image" : self.avatarBase64String]
```

When I send a request, I got following in console:

> FAILURE:
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

My base64 string is correct (quite lot of symbols though), but I did check it online and got an image from output.

Why I got such an error?

Comment: The error mentions “response”. The server may send something else than JSON to you. Can you print the response as raw data or as a string?

Comment: @Ahmad F problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban glad to help! all I did was editing the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your network connection. 
Then you convert the `imageView` into Data and then convert into base64

Hope this code will help you:-

```
 let pic  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cameraView.image, 0.5)
 let avatarBase64String = pic.base64EncodedString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have been using in order to make easy Dictionary representation of your parameters in order to make a POST request with Alamofire.

You can use this in your model class:

```
var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {

        return [
            "name" : self.name,
            "title" : self.title,
            "avatar" : self.avatar,
            "age" : self.age,
        ]
    }
```

> You can remove the self if you are in your model class, it is just for a better understanding.

And then when you want to make your POST request, you can call it this way :

Imagine you have a class User, with attribute name, title, avatar and age as previously shown.

And you want to send your object User to your backend.

Here is how you can send your parameters as dictionary represented :

```
let user = User(name: name, title: title, avatar: avatar; age: age) 

CustomService.shared.post(parameters: user.dictionaryRepresentation) { response in
   // Handle response here
 }
```

I strongly recommend you to abstract in a shared Service class all the networking methods.